# Use unique column names to group objects in an Eloquent Collection

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a `User` model for a typical `users` table with fields `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `user_name`, `occupation`, `password`, `remember_token`, `created_at` and `updated_at`.

`User::all()` returns all users in a collection. Now how do I list the `user` objects under the `occupation` field in the collection. i.e. I want to have this:

```
[
    {
        doctor: [
            {
                id: 1,
                firstname: "John",
                lastname: "Dalisay",
                gender: "male",
                email: "john@example.com",
                username: "john123",
                created: "2012-01-15 07:26:14",
                modified: "2012-01-15 07:26:14"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                firstname: "Jem",
                lastname: "Panlilio",
                gender: "male",
                email: "jemboy09@example.com",
                username: "jem123",
                created: "2012-01-15 07:26:46",
                modified: "2012-01-15 07:26:46"
            }
        ],

        engineer: [
            {
                id: 3,
                firstname: "Jaylord",
                lastname: "Bitamug",
                gender: "male",
                email: "jayjay@example.com",
                username: "jay123",
                created: "2012-01-15 07:27:04",
                modified: "2012-01-15 07:27:04"
            },

                {
                id: 4,
                firstname: "Darwin",
                lastname: "Dalisay",
                gender: "male",
                email: "dada08@example.com",
                username: "dada123",
                created: "2012-01-15 07:25:34",
                modified: "2012-01-15 07:25:34"
            }
        ]
    } ....
]
```

I have tried with `groupBy` but was not successful.

Comment: What is the result you get with groupBy?

Comment: This: [
 {
  id: 12,
  firstname: "abdur",
  lastname: "rahim",
  occupation: "doctor",
  email: null,
  username: "rahim",
  created: null,
  modified: "2015-03-30 19:06:18"
 },
 {
  id: 6,
  firstname: "Sandra",
  lastname: "Bullock",
  occupation: "engineer",
  email: "sundra@example.com",
  username: "jun123",
  created: "2012-02-05 10:15:14",
  modified: "2015-05-03 10:51:12"
 },
 ...
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database aggregates does not work in the way you expect with the expample provided.

To obtain the desired result try this:

```
$users = User::all();
$groupByOccupation = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
   $groupByOccupation[$user->occupation][] = $user;
}

//Now you can return your $groupByOccupation var to view or convertit to JSON
```

I Hope this works for you.